# Best way to handle ActiveRecord where clauses with three types of joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

What's the best way to find all objects that have various children that match certain attribute IDs?

Take the following models:

Top level models:

```
class InstagramPost < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :instagram_post_hashtags
  has_many :instagram_post_mentions
  has_many :instagram_post_locations
end

class InstagramHashtag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :instagram_post_hashtags
  has_many :instagram_posts, through: :instagram_post_hashtags
end

class InstagramMention < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :instagram_post_mentions
  has_many :instagram_posts, through: :instagram_post_mentions
end

class InstagramLocation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :instagram_post_locations
  has_many :instagram_posts, through: :instagram_post_locations
end
```

Joins:

```
class InstagramPostHashtag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :instagram_hashtag
  belongs_to :instagram_post
end

class InstagramPostLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :instagram_location
  belongs_to :instagram_post
end

class InstagramPostMention < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :instagram_mention
  belongs_to :instagram_post
end
```

Now say I have three arrays of IDs:

```
instagram_hashtag_ids = [12,20,23]
instagram_location_ids = [4,12,30]
instagram_mention_ids = [121,21,31]
```

If I wanted to find all `InstagramPost` that have `InstagramPostHashtag`, `InstagramPostLocation`, and `InstagramPostMention` that must match all of the above array IDs; I was thinking I could do something like:

```
@instagram_posts = InstagramPost.joins(:instagram_post_hashtags).where("instagram_post_hashtags.instagram_hashtag_id IN (#{instagram_hashtag_ids})")
```

Then take those results, and do a search on the next array:

```
@instagram_posts = @instagram_posts.joins(:instagram_post_locations).where("instagram_post_locations.instagram_location_id IN (#{instagram_location_ids})")
```

and so on...

This seems like a pretty bad way to do this, because if there's no IDs in the array, it'll come back empty. In fact, most of the time it comes back with no results even when all arrays have IDs in them and there's data to reflect that (maybe a problem with PostgreSQL?).

What's the best way to query the `InstagramPost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch all `InstagramPost`s which have joins tables matching given arrays of ids:

```
@instagram_posts = InstagramPost.joins(
  :instagram_post_hashtags,
  :instagram_post_mentions,
  :instagram_post_locations
).where(
  instagram_post_hashtags: { instagram_hashtag_id: instagram_hashtag_ids },
  instagram_post_locations: { instagram_location_id: instagram_location_ids }, 
  instagram_post_mentions: { instagram_mention_id: instagram_mention_ids }
)
```